# AES GCM in PHP/Java

Tags: aes

I have to write the encryption/decryption library in AES-256 with GCM block mode.
I have written the same in java and it is working fine.

Here is the code :

```
private static final int GCM_IV_SIZE_BYTES = 12;
    private static final int GCM_TAG_SIZE_BYTES = 16;
    private static final int GCM_SALT_SIZE_BYTES = 16;
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plaintext, byte[] dataKey, String version) throws Exception
    {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // Generate Initialization Vector
        byte[] IV = generateIV();
        
        // Get Cipher Instance
        Cipher cipher = getCipher();
        
        // Get Salt
        byte[] salt = generateSalt();
        
        // Store Version
        byte[] versionArr = new byte[3];
        versionArr = version.getBytes();
        
        // Generate Key
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(dataKey, "AES");
    
        // Create GCMParameterSpec
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_TAG_SIZE_BYTES * 8, IV);
        
        // Initialize Cipher for ENCRYPT_MODE
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, gcmParameterSpec);
        
        // Perform Encryption
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
        
        
        
        int capacity = 3 + GCM_SALT_SIZE_BYTES + GCM_IV_SIZE_BYTES + plaintext.length + GCM_TAG_SIZE_BYTES;
        
        // Create ByteBuffer & add SALT, IV & CipherText
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(capacity);
        buffer.put(versionArr);
        buffer.put(salt);
        buffer.put(IV);
        buffer.put(cipherText);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Encryption Time : "+(endTime - startTime)+"ms");
        // return the final encrypted cipher txt
        return buffer.array();
    }

public static String decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] dataKey) throws Exception
    {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (cipherText.length < GCM_IV_SIZE_BYTES + GCM_TAG_SIZE_BYTES + GCM_SALT_SIZE_BYTES) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(cipherText);
    
        byte[]version = new byte[3];
        buffer.get(version, 0, version.length);
        
        System.out.println(new String(version));
        // Get Salt from Cipher
        byte[] salt = new byte[GCM_SALT_SIZE_BYTES];
        buffer.get(salt, 0, salt.length);
        System.out.println(new String(salt));
        // GET IV from cipher
        byte[] ivBytes1 = new byte[GCM_IV_SIZE_BYTES];
        buffer.get(ivBytes1, 0, ivBytes1.length);
        System.out.println(new String(ivBytes1));
        byte[] encryptedTextBytes = new byte[buffer.capacity() - salt.length - ivBytes1.length- 3];
        buffer.get(encryptedTextBytes);
        
        System.out.println("enc tect bytes");
        System.out.println(new String(encryptedTextBytes));
        // Get Cipher Instance
        Cipher cipher = getCipher();
        
        // Generate Key
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(dataKey, "AES");
        
        // Create GCMParameterSpec
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_TAG_SIZE_BYTES * 8, ivBytes1);
        
        // Initialize Cipher for DECRYPT_MODE
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, gcmParameterSpec);
        
        // Perform Decryption
        byte[] decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextBytes);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Decryption Time : "+(endTime - startTime)+"ms");
        return new String(decryptedText);
    }
```

Now the issue is I have to write the same library in PHP and then I have to encrypt using PHP library and decrypt using Java library / vice-versa

Here is my PHP code for encryption:

```
function encrypt($key, $textToEncrypt){
    $cipher = 'aes-256-gcm';
    $iv_len = 12;
    $tag_length = 16;
    $version_length = 3;
    $salt_length = 16;

    $version = "v01";
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_len);
    $salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($salt_length);
    $tag = ""; // will be filled by openssl_encrypt
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($textToEncrypt, $cipher, $key, 0, $iv, $tag, "", $tag_length);

    $encrypted = base64_encode($version.$salt.$iv.$ciphertext.$tag);
    return $encrypted;

}
```

Now the issue is, when I am encrypting the data using PHP and then trying to decrypt it using Java code, getting below exception

```
:Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:578)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1049)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:985)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:847)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
```

What am I missing here?

Base64 in PHP code is present, same is present in Java code while calling the encode/decode functions, hence not present in this post code.

Comment: Why is there only a base64 in the php code and not in the Java code?  Did you verify inputs? (Ea are they what you expect at each stage))

Comment: Forgot to mention this, this I have handled. When I am calling java code, there I am using it.

Comment: You are using php > 7.1.0 ?

Comment: 7.2.24 ? Does this matter. I am testing the code on PHp 7.2, but I will have to run this later on PHP 5.6

Comment: I see that tag, tag_length are added after PHP 7.1. So Cant we use aes gcm with PHP 5.6?

Comment: Yes. It matters. Take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php I would not be using php 5.6 in production anymore (it’s way past it’s end of life & full of performance bottlenecks & security holes). I suspect your double base64 encoding, check the option parameter for the RAW option.

Comment: I see that tag, tag_length are added after PHP 7.1. So Cant we use aes gcm with PHP 5.6

Comment: I don’t know. It depends on the OpenSSL version with which php was compiled. (There is a way to get the supported cipher list for a reason in php)

Comment: First, I'm afraid this is off topic here. We don't perform code reviews or coding help. Second, please don't use PHP 5. It is dead and will only become more insecure over time. Trying to secure a PHP 5 application is like putting a deadbolt on a screen door.

Comment: Finally, don't roll your own crypto code. There is never a good reason to, and there are far too many things you can get wrong without even realizing it. Just don't do it. Especially in languages that are dead.

Comment: Why are you including a salt? Salts are for password hashing - not encryption

Comment: FIne. Will remove the salt. But can you answer the original question with PHP 5,6 / 7.2

Comment: Read the php.net documentation on the OpenSSL functions...

Comment: as per openssl supported function, aes-256-gcm is there but how can i use tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cross-platform encryption between PHP and Java using AES GCM mode is working. There are some details that may prevent you from a successful doing.

First: On PHP-side the openssl_encrypt returns a base64 encoded ciphertext that is again base64 encoded when concatenating the ciphertext with the version, iv and tag. To avoid this I set the OPENSSL-option to "OPENSSL_RAW_DATA".

Second: on Java-side the tag is appended to the ciphertext so the "ciphertext|tag" can get consumed directly.

Just a note: my examples are just showing how the encryption on PHP-side and decryption on Java-side will work but may have nothing to do with your source codes (special on Java side) - I was to lazy to adopt my example :-)

This is the output on PHP-side:

```
AES GCM in PHP/Java
ciphertext: djAx/kMbxfJI5Zx7lTWeDbw601cD2wkjBvuKeVBbKOZHll98GstPNfi1xHvyRlBwJDQ6YWvpymsk76kwbBbD0cBsOzzK/tH8UpA=
```

Copy the ciphertext to the Java program and let it run:

```
AES GCM in PHP/Java
decryptedtext: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Below you find the source codes for both programs. **Security warning: the codes are using fixed and hard-coded keys - don't do
this. The programs do not have any exception handling and are for educational purpose only.**

The code is running on PHP > 7.2 and Java 11+.

PHP-code:

```
<?php
function encrypt($key, $textToEncrypt){
    $cipher = 'aes-256-gcm';
    $iv_len = 12;
    $tag_length = 16;
    $version_length = 3;
    $version = "v01";
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_len);
    $tag = ""; // will be filled by openssl_encrypt
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($textToEncrypt, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag, "", $tag_length);
    $encrypted = base64_encode($version.$iv.$ciphertext.$tag);
    return $encrypted;
}

echo 'AES GCM in PHP/Java' . PHP_EOL;
// ### security warning: never use hardcoded keys in source ###
$key = '12345678901234567890123456789012';
$plaintext = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
$ciphertext = encrypt($key, $plaintext);
echo 'ciphertext: ' . $ciphertext . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Java-code:

```
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

public class SO_final {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
        System.out.println("AES GCM in PHP/Java");
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65001817/aes-gcm-in-php-java
        String ciphertext = "djAx/kMbxfJI5Zx7lTWeDbw601cD2wkjBvuKeVBbKOZHll98GstPNfi1xHvyRlBwJDQ6YWvpymsk76kwbBbD0cBsOzzK/tH8UpA=";
        // ### security warning: never use hardcoded keys in source ###
        byte[] key = "12345678901234567890123456789012".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String decryptedtext = decryptGcmBase64(key, ciphertext);
        System.out.println("decryptedtext: " + decryptedtext);
    }

    public static String decryptGcmBase64(byte[] key, String ciphertextBase64) throws
            NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        byte[] ciphertextComplete = Base64.getDecoder().decode(ciphertextBase64);
        // split data
        // base64 encoding $encrypted = base64_encode($version.$iv.$ciphertext.$tag);
        byte[] version = Arrays.copyOfRange(ciphertextComplete, 0, 3); // 3 bytes
        byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(ciphertextComplete, 3, 15); // 12 bytes
        byte[] ciphertextWithTag = Arrays.copyOfRange(ciphertextComplete, 15, ciphertextComplete.length);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(16 * 8, iv);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding");//NOPadding
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, gcmParameterSpec);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(ciphertextWithTag), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am using PHP 7.2 / Java 8 and its working(used a art of your code). Now is there a way I can use this wth PHP 5.6

Comment: As I'm no longer working with PHP 5.x I can't help you in that question, but I saw there are still pure PHP codes for AES GCM mode available (e.g. on Github). Could you kindly mark my answer as accepted one - thanks ?