# AES 256 bit GCM java equivalent code for php encryption and decryption

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes-gcm

I am trying to understand java code and want to covert that to equivalent php code for AES 256 bit GCM No Padding option.
If I encrypt some text using both java and php encryption algorithm then result should be same. Please note I have a fixed key and IV value available which will be used in java and php side.

Below is the java code function to encrypt

```
public static final int AES_KEY_SIZE = 256;
public static final int GCM_IV_LENGTH = 12;
public static final int GCM_TAG_LENGTH = 16;

public static String encrypt(String plainText, String encryptionKey, String IV) throws Exception {
    
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
    
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_TAG_LENGTH * 8, IV.getBytes());
    
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,gcmParameterSpec);
    
        byte[] cipherByte = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
    
        String cipherText = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherByte));
         
        return cipherText;
       
    }
```

I have idea that I can use php openssl_encrypt function for encryption but I am unable to understand some part of java code

```
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_TAG_LENGTH * 8, IV.getBytes());
```

can some java/php expert help me to understand about lines of code what new SeceretKeySpec is actually doing and GCMParmeters how these work. what would be equivalent in php for doing same operation?

Below is the php code

```
function encrypt($key, $textToEncrypt,$iv){
    $cipher = 'aes-256-gcm';
    $iv_len = 12;
    $tag_length = 16;
    $tag = ""; 
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($textToEncrypt, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag, "", $tag_length);
    $encrypted = base64_encode($ciphertext);
    return $encrypted;
}
```

I already did some research on stackoverflow but could not find equivalent solution for php.
like [AES GCM in PHP/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65001817/aes-gcm-in-php-java)

Comment: Without going further - there is an obvious error: "Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");". Try to exchange with **GCM**

Comment: ya sorry there was GCM in java code actually I mixed two codes. let me correct the question

Comment: Apart from this typo, both codes are (almost) identical, i.e. provide the same ciphertext for the same input data. The difference is that in the Java code ciphertext and tag are implicitly concatenated (`ciphertext|tag`), while in the PHP code both are handled separately. For the PHP code to return the same result as the Java code `$encrypted = base64_encode($ciphertext . $tag)` must be used.

Comment: In the Java code the encoding should be explicitly specified in all `getBytes()` (otherwise provider-dependent default values are used).

Comment: @Topaco Thanks for your reply. but as the $tag is blank in php so concatenating would not create any difference.

Comment: *...as the $tag is blank in php so concatenating would not create any difference...* You are wrong. During encryption the tag is generated and passed by reference, s. the docs for [`openssl_encrypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php).

Comment: ok so if I again want to decrypt encrypted string using php then i would base64_decode first then to extract tag again this will be like  $tag = substr( $textToDecrypt , $iv_len , 16 ); ?

Comment: If `$textToDecrypt` is the concatenation of ciphertext and tag, then `$ct_len = strlen($textToDecrypt) - $tag_length` is the length of the ciphertext. The ciphertext is then `$ct = substr($textToDecrypt, 0, $ct_len)` and the tag `$tag = substr($textToDecrypt, $ct_len, $tag_length)`.

Comment: @Topaco Thanks for your quick replies. so basically my question is answered in your first comment. let me know how to mark your reply as answer.